# Angular Material Tab focus with Tabulator button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following angular material `tab-group`:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab  tabindex="0" cdkTrapFocus label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab  tabindex="1" cdkTrapFocus label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab  tabindex="2" cdkTrapFocus label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

(from [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pmdoylygpdj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-align-example.html) )

Currently, I must improve the a11y aspects of this, and the request is that the user should be able to navigate the tabs with the "Tab" button on the keyboard. The default way in material is that you can only focus the "tab-group" as a whole, and then can select the `mat-tab`s with the arrow keys.

Is there any way to change this? To integrate the tabs themselves into the focus order instead of the groups?

You can see I have tried `cdkTrapFocus` and `tabIndex` as well but no luck. I also tried removing the `mat-tab-group` but strangely only the first `mat-tab` gets focus that way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keydown event could be the solution

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" [(selectedIndex)]=selectedStartIndex (keydown)="onKey($event, 'start')">
    <!-- #enddocregion align-start -->
    <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" [(selectedIndex)]=selectedCenterIndex (keydown)="onKey($event, 'center')">
    <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="end" [(selectedIndex)]=selectedEndIndex (keydown)="onKey($event, 'end')">
    <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Tab group with aligned labels
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-align-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-align-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab-group-align-example.css']
})
export class TabGroupAlignExample {
  selectedStartIndex: any = 0;
  selectedCenterIndex: any = 0;
  selectedEndIndex: any = 0;
  selectedGroup: String = '';
  onKey(event: KeyboardEvent, group: String) {
    if (event.key == 'Tab')
      switch (group) {
        case 'start':
          if (this.selectedGroup != group) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.selectedStartIndex = 0;
          } else if (this.selectedStartIndex < 2) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.selectedStartIndex++;
          }
          this.selectedGroup = group;
          break;
        case 'center':
          if (this.selectedGroup != group) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.selectedCenterIndex = 0;
          } else if (this.selectedCenterIndex < 2) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.selectedCenterIndex++;
          }
          this.selectedGroup = group;
          break;
        case 'end':
          if (this.selectedGroup != group) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.selectedEndIndex = 0;
          } else if (this.selectedEndIndex < 2) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.selectedEndIndex++;
          }
          this.selectedGroup = group;
          break;
      }
  }
}
```